# Cannot trigger submit button with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I am trying to trigger a function when the form submit button is clicked. I tried both with click and submit methods but it is not triggered. Any advice would be greately appreciated.

```
<form id="my_form" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" id="subm" class=" submit_button"  value="Submit" >
</form>   

$("#subm").click(function() {
alert('Doesnt work');
}

$("#my_form").submit(function() {
alert('Doesnt work');
}
```

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with `php`. Please fix your questions tags...

Comment: Do you get any hints in your browsers development console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add Jquery library to work and then you have to use `preventDefault()` like below:-

```
<form id="my_form" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" id="subm" class=" submit_button"  value="Submit" >
</form>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ // After document is completly loaded
    $("#subm").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submit on click
       alert('Does work'); //alert the message
    });// you missed ); here
}); 

</script>
```

Note:- check your browser development console and you will exactly get what errors are there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ // After document is completly loaded
        $("#subm").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submit on click
           alert('Does work'); //alert the message
        });// you missed ); here
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form" action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" id="subm" class=" submit_button"  value="Submit" >
</form>
```